# I would like to trigger a mouseup event, after it has been already triggered with exact same parameters

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

I would like to capture the `event` of a mouse up, and replay it exactly.

i am able to capture the old event mouseup event, put it inside the 'temp1' variable and try to re-trigger again.

```
$('#mycanvas').on("mouseup", function(e) {
  window.temp1= e;
});
```

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initEvent("mouseup", true, true);
document.getElementById("mycanvas").dispatchEvent(temp1);
```

I would like to replay the exact mouse up event but I get an error:

> "VM39941:3 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on
>   'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'."

This is for a small tool of mine, I understand that what I am doing is nonstandard.

Comment: Are you sure `temp1` is defined when you are trying to dispatch the event ?

Comment: try `.dispatchEvent(evt);`

Comment: Can you put here print screen what do you have in "temp1"?

Comment: the temp1 ( without window ) is the event captured. It is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`dispatchEvent()` can only dispatch events that are created via `Event()` constructors. For this case, you can create a [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) and copy over all of the relevant properties you need from the original event:

```js
div.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
    console.log('moused up on div');

    var evt = new MouseEvent('mouseup', {
        altKey: event.altKey,
        bubbles: event.bubbles,
        cancelable: event.cancelable,
        button: event.button,
        buttons: event.buttons,
        clientX: event.clientX,
        clientY: event.clientY,
        ctrlKey: event.ctrlKey,
        detail: event.detail,
        metaKey: event.metaKey,
        relatedTarget: event.relatedTarget,
        screenX: event.screenX,
        screenY: event.screenY,
        shiftKey: event.shiftKey,
        type: event.type,
        view: event.view
    });

    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="div">Block 1</div>
```

n.b. you may be creating an infinite cycle of `mouseup` events.